# I'm having a problem with sending a char pointer to a function and assigning a value to it in C

Tags: arrays, c, char, printf, c-strings

I am trying to register to the address I sent to the function in the code structure you see below. But the for loop itself adds something. It only does this on arrays of 11 elements. That is, if `"Hasan Polat"` comes, he adds it, but if `"Hasann Polat"` comes, he does not add it. Or anything other than any 11 element array.printf output is written next to it

```
void sezarSifreleme(char cumle[], int kaydirma, char *sifreliCumle) {
    
      char alfabe[26] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
      int i,j, cumleUzunluk = strlen(cumle);

      for(i=0; i < cumleUzunluk; i++) {
          if(cumle[i]==' ') {
              cumle[i] = ' ';
          } else {
          for(j=0;j < 26; j++){
              if(cumle[i] == alfabe[j]){
                  j = j + kaydirma;
                  j = j % 26; // Sezar sifrelemede sona geldikten sonra basa donulur onu saglamak amacli 26'ya mod aliriz.
                  cumle[i] = alfabe[j];
                  break;
              }
          }
       }


printf("**");
// Sonucu main fonk icerisine gondermek icin aldigimiz degisken adresine sifreledigimiz cumleyi atiyoruz
for(i=0; i < cumleUzunluk; i++) {
    
    sifreliCumle[i] = cumle[i];
    printf("%c", sifreliCumle[i]); // **mfxfs utqfy**
}
printf("**");

printf("??%s??", sifreliCumle); // ??mfxfs utqfy??
}
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation so your code is readable.

Comment: @Hasan Polat Show how the function is called and how its arguments are defined.

Comment: My problem is that it makes a ridiculous addition after the for loop. and this insertion only happens in 11 element array.

Comment: @HasanPolat What is unclear in my comment?

Comment: `printf("%s"...)` expects a pointer to a string as argument i.e. a pointer to a nul-terminated character sequence. Does that match your input?

Comment: `cumle[i] = ' ';` That looks a bit strange. You can just use empty brackets if you don't want to do anything in that case. You could also invert the condition in your `if` and drop that first branch completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account these two outputs: one with the fixed number of characters `cumleUzunluk` in the for loop

```
printf("**");
// Sonucu main fonk icerisine gondermek icin aldigimiz degisken adresine sifreledigimiz cumleyi atiyoruz
for(i=0; i < cumleUzunluk; i++) {
    
    sifreliCumle[i] = cumle[i];
    printf("%c", sifreliCumle[i]); // **mfxfs utqfy**
}
printf("**");
```

and other with using the conversion specifier `s`

```
printf("??%s??", sifreliCumle); // ??mfxfs utqfy??
```

it means that at least the pointer `sifreliCumle` does not point to a string.

You could rewrite this call of `printf` the following way

```
printf("??%.*s??", cumleUzunluk, sifreliCumle);
```

or append the zero character `'\0'` provided that the array pointed to by the pointer `sifreliCumle` have a space to store the zero character `'\0'` as for example

```
sifreliCumle[cumleUzunluk] = '\0';
printf("??%s??", sifreliCumle);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your code is doing, but I see that you have this routine:

```
void sezarSifreleme(char cumle[], int kaydirma, char *sifreliCumle)
```

and it is defined as having a void return.  I see you maninpulating the pointers inside the routine, but none are remained modified outside the routine unless you either use pointer to pointers are you return the pointer in function signature.

```
char * sezarSifreleme(char cumle[], int kaydirma, char *sifreliCumle)

...
return sifreliCumle;
```

What is that anyway? Signed Integer, free, li cumulative, little endian?

Comment: *What is that anyway?* Rumors say that English is not the only language....

Comment: *I see you maninpulating the pointers inside the routine* You might want to look again. The pointers are not changed. The memory where they point to is modified which is perfectly OK.

Comment: Yes, that is a good point.  I did not translate the non english comment.